# Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, graphics, intel-graphics, opengl

I'm using Intel HD Graphics as graphics card and I'm trying to open an OpenGL program, but,
when I try to run it, I have the following error: 
    OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ':0.0'

Then, I tried to run `glxinfo`, then I had the:

```
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig ubuntu 12.04 error.
```

How can I fix this error from not happening again?

Comment: this seems to be a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1278168

Comment: i've already uninstalled Xserver-Xorg, but I'm still with the problem.

Comment: now it's working, when i reinstalled Xserver-xorg, i forgot to reboot my computer, thanks for your help!

Comment: could you provide your answer please with complete workaround what did you do, so that your answer might help future readers.

Answer (score 2):

To solve my problem I had to enter the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg

sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

And then: `sudo reboot`

But I think that if you on pure text mode, you don't need to reboot your computer, but you would have to do `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm stop` before you type the commands I mentioned above and, after typing then, you will have to use `sudo /etc/init.d/gdm start` to start the graphic interface again.

Comment: Purging also removed `ubuntu-desktop`, `ubuntustudio-desktop` and `xorg` package. Recording here for @snafu after reboot.

Comment: Nah, reinstalling `xserver-xorg` didn't help.

Comment: Didn't have to do the `--purge` to get it working on my Lenovo laptop with an NVIDIA GeForce 920M card. I thought this issue was connected to my graphics drivers that are not being utilised properly, but thanks to your suggestion I know that it isn't.

Comment: Didn't work for me, what worked was: sudo apt-get --reinstall install libgl1-mesa-dri and then reboot. (Problem happened after a failed proprietary AMD drivers install.)

Comment: **This is a harmful answer, and users following this advice tend to kill their desktop.** Many of them will need to reinstall because they don't see any other way out.