# How do i get back my desktop after having purged the xserver-xorg package?

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, xorg

I purged the xserver-xorg package and now when i start my laptop it shows a black screen only saying:

```
overlayfs: missing ‘lowerdir’
```

I remember when I purged the package it said that it would delete 4 packages. IIRC, two of them were `kubuntu-desktop` and `xserver-xorg`. The third being something like `sdm` and the last I can’t remember.

I have tried going into recovery mode at boot and repairing and it installed 4 packages, but one of them was thunderbird which I am sure wasn’t one of the packages I deleted. So it seems like I am missing one.

What do I do?

I just installed Kubuntu 21.10, and I’m very new to it all, so I hope you can help me.

---

#### Edit

I went in to boot recovery mode and chose the `dpkg` option. It installed some packages includen kubuntu-desktop, but it still didn't work.

I had to `sudo apt install sddm`, and then after i rebooted it all worked again.

Comment: It sounds like you removed your GUI & desktop, turning your system into a text based server?  Why did you remove `xorg-server`  ... which mandated removal of `xorg` `kubuntu-desktop` etc..?  (sdm?  I gather `sddm` to you have no GUI greeter not that it matters without xorg)    Your results were expected?  (Kubuntu/GUI is gone as cannot exist given your purge).   What were you trying to do?  You've removed Kubuntu now leaving Ubuntu base (closest to a Ubuntu Server system)  I'd suggest `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop` but we can only help if provided pastes of your messages

Comment: I listened to some advice in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/475972/error-couldnt-find-rgb-glx-visual-or-fbconfig-ubuntu-12-04) because of problems with glx and Steam. But that was a bad idea.

I installed sddm and now it works! thank you:)

Interesting experience:)

Comment: You should've payed attention to the comments. I don't understand why such a poor answer gets so many votes. And the hardware is totally different than yours, unlikely anything tested there is applicable. You should've started by checking if you have the recommended Nvidia drivers and go from there.

Comment: Well well i guess im new to this whole thing both Ubuntu and askubuntu. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Boot back into your recovery prompt, and reinstall `kubuntu-desktop`, as

```
sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

This is a small metapackage configure to depend on all packages deemed essential for a functioning Kubuntu desktop. Having removed that `xserver-xorg` packages should have removed that metapackage as well. Reinstalling it should pull back in any critical package that is missing.

Comment: I tried that but only after installing the sddm package as well it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Start by booting into [the recovery mode](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).

After you are in a root shell, Run the below command:

```
apt install kubuntu-desktop
```

Information regarding the package can be find [here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/kubuntu-desktop).

---

If the above didn't worked for you, then run:

```
apt install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop^
```

The ^ indicates [task package](https://askubuntu.com/a/257172/1460940).

---

You can also install [other desktop environments](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.howtogeek.com/193129/how-to-install-and-use-another-desktop-environment-on-linux/amp/).

Comment: Wierdly it seemed that after i had tried `apt install kubuntu-desktop` it installed 3 packages but it still didn't work. Only because @guiverc told me the name of the sddm package i could install it and then everything worked again:) Thanks for the help though:)